# How to add environment in Grails

Tags: exception, grails, groovy, environment

I am attempting to add an environment to a Grails 2.4.4 app, as documented:
http://docs.grails.org/2.4.4/guide/conf.html#environments

I have added configuration for this environment to all of
`Config.groovy, DataSource.groovy, and BootStrap.groovy` as documented.

However, when I attempt to execute my unit tests in this environment with the command `grails -Dgrails.env=shippable test-app --unit --stacktrace`, I receive an exception that I am unable to find a cause for:

```
| Compiling 16 source files.
| Error Error executing script TestApp: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method newInstance() on null object (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method newInstance() on null object
    at _Events$_run_closure2_closure7.doCall(_Events.groovy:24)
    at _Events$_run_closure2.doCall(_Events.groovy:22)
    at _Events$_run_closure2.doCall(_Events.groovy)
    at _Events$_run_closure4.doCall(_Events.groovy:33)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.BuildListener$targetStarted.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_withTargetEvent_closure1.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:89)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:89)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at TestApp$_run_closure1.doCall(TestApp.groovy:32)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
| Error Error executing script TestApp: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method newInstance() on null object
```

Lines 18-28 of _Events.groovy are shown here:

```
        Closure installBowerNotification = {
        event 'StatusError', [
            "Failed to install front-end javascript dependencies. " +
            "If you're not working on the CMS, it's safe to ignore " +
            "this message. "
        ]
        event 'StatusError', [
            'Please install Yarn and Bower as described in the README. ' +
            '(i.e., `brew install yarn && yarn global add bower`)'
        ]
```

Comment: Is `_Events.groovy` your own custom one in your app?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown There is a custom _Events.groovy containing a 'eventCompileEnd'.

Comment: Can you provide that custom _Events.groovy file here?  Or failing that, at least the relevant parts?  I'm guessing there's something on line 24 that's worth a second look.  That, or this is coming from some other _Events.groovy file...

Comment: @Daniel Posted above. Thank you for pointing that out! I erroneously assumed that was internal Grails code. Line 24 is ```event 'StatusError',```

Comment: Strangely enough, when I delete the custom _Events.groovy and do a `grails clean` and rerun the test command, I receive the same build exception.

Comment: Definitely not coming from your custom events then.  I don't actually have 2.4.4 downloaded at the moment, but I do have 2.5.1 which is similar in a lot of ways.  I looked through the _Events.groovy's that I have and the one coming from webxml-1.4.1 has a FilterManager.newInstance() on line 24.  That seems like quite the coincidence.  This is heading deep into "You should wait for Jeff" territory, but is there anything unusual or broken in your web.xml that might cause the FilterManager to be null?

Comment: The only change to web.xml since 2013 appears to be making changes similar to this to enable CORS: http://dontpanic.42.nl/2015/04/cors-with-spring-mvc.html

Comment: Another oddity: `fixWebXml()` which contains line 24 in webxml's _Events.groovy is only called inside a try-catch block by eventWebXmlEnd. So I'm unsure how the exception is causing execution to end.